# How to port COMPLETED libgdx game from Android to iOS

Tags: android, libgdx

I have completed game on top of libgdx: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drobus.basketpro Is there any workable way to port it to iOS?

Comment: Isn't that the point of using libgdx?

Comment: There is a lot to learn from. But I look for real example/experience

Comment: @KolesnikovichDmitry did you manage to release the game in iOS? If so, how was the performance, app size, admob integration and google play game service integration?

Comment: I use RoboVM now. It's good for simple games. http://robovm.com

Comment: this is the game itself https://itunes.apple.com/app/id958917938

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple options, but both are not truly production ready solutions. Options below are 'mostly' working. A few features will not work out of box without some custom handling (networking, sound, and a few others).

- [RoboVM](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3063) (free)
- [MonoTouch/IKVM](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IOSWIP) ($299 + Apple licence)

These methods work and are currently the best (easy) solutions available to you.

Note that RoboVM is supported by libGDX out-of-the-box as the default iOS target cross-compiler.

**Update:**

PS: RoboVM is not permanently free anymore. See [here](https://robovm.com/pricing/). You get a 30 day trial, then it costs 25$/month minimum.

Comment: RoboVM is still [free for use with libGDX](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3762), and the second option has been deprecated in favor of RoboVM.

Comment: RoboVM is now called mobidevelop RoboVM. You can find an updated tutorial [here](https://jesusredondo.github.io/project/2017/03/03/VideoGame_design_II_Deploying_on_iOS.html)

Answer (score 1):

A more recent guide on how to accomplish this can be found here:
https://medium.com/@apiric/deploying-your-libgdx-game-to-ios-testflight-163cada0696b

Short version:
Install RoboVM version 2.3.10-SNAPSHOT ([link](http://robovm.mobidevelop.com/downloads/snapshots/idea/))
Create an Xcode project with the same build id as your Libgdx project
Run the Xcode project on your iPhone/iPad
Create an IOSLauncher.ipa file in Android Studio by typing `.gradlew ios:createIPA`
Create an “Apple Distribution” signing identity and an “App Store” provisioning profile
Install fastlane ([link](https://docs.fastlane.tools/))
Certify and upload your project using fastlane

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I will make the proper adjustments.